# Regular expression to replace <

Tags: java, mysql, sql, regex, oracle

I have the data below,Is any way to write common regular expression to get desired output in oracle using regexp_replace function.

```
<Tier><grade><><sdlc><17,10><>  : result should be 17.10
<><sdlc><16,909312> :   16.909312
<><sdlc><11396,87> :11396.87
<20121217>        :20121217
<UNIT><6086>  : 6086
<Tier1><><sdlc><0,47> :0.47
```

Comment: Thanks Reimeus,But i want it using regular expression,that is the limitation i have it.

Comment: Is your data XML ? if so, better read this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @shellter His question is quite clear. `<Tier><grade><><sdlc><17,10><>` convert to `17.10`

Comment: @shellter It happens cuz we just took brief look and miss details. Happens to best of us. ;-}

Answer (score 2):

You could you a simple regex like below:

Steps:

- Replace `,` witha `.`
- use regex to find a match

Code:

```
String s="<Tier><grade><><sdlc><17,10><>";
            s = s.replace(',', '.');
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.*\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group());// 17.10
        }
```

Comment: thanks,How it works for other fields :<><sdlc><16,909312> :   16.909312
<><sdlc><11396,87> :11396.87
<20121217>        :20121217
<UNIT><6086>  : 6086
<Tier1><><sdlc><0,47> :0.47

Comment: apply the same regex for other aswell.

Comment: how to use this in oracle regexp_replace function?

Comment: hmm, i am not quite sure how to do this in oracle as i am not familiar with oracle's regex engine, i suggest you to update thequestion as how to parse this string using oracle regex, you'd get more help.